# .NET IL ByteCode Optimizer

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, bytecode, il

I'm trying to write optimized code in C# .NET and Mono that will be used for games.  (Yes I have valid reasons for using C# and not C++).

I notice C# does not seem to optimize its operators correctly.  Operators run twice as slow vs manually inlining the code with Vector4 math.
Here are some simple benchmark tests I did in .NET 4.5 running 9999999 times:

```
// Test 1
for (uint i = 0; i != 9999999; ++i)// 230 MS
{
  vector += vector2;
  vector2 -= vector;
}

// Test 2
for (uint i = 0; i != 9999999; ++i)// 185 MS
{
  vector = vector.Add(ref vector2);
  vector2 = vector2.Sub(ref vector);
}

// Test 3
for (uint i = 0; i != 9999999; ++i)// 116 MS
{
  vector.X += vector2.X;
  vector.Y += vector2.Y;
  vector.Z += vector2.Z;
  vector.W += vector2.W;
  vector2.X -= vector1.X;
  vector2.Y -= vector1.Y;
  vector2.Z -= vector1.Z;
  vector2.W -= vector1.W;
}

// EDIT Test 1 SOLVED ----------------------------------
// When the Operators are created like so, they actually perform the BEST!
// Sry MS for complaining :(...  Although SIMD support would be nice :)
struct Vector4
{
    public static Vector4 operator +(Vector4 p1, Vector4 p2)
{
    p1.X += p2.X;
    p1.Y += p2.Y;
    p1.Z += p2.Z;
    p1.W += p2.W;
    return p1;
}

public static Vector4 operator -(Vector4 p1, Vector4 p2)
{
    p1.X -= p2.X;
    p1.Y -= p2.Y;
    p1.Z -= p2.Z;
    p1.W -= p2.W;
    return p1;
}
}

for (uint i = 0; i != 9999999; ++i)// 75 MS
{
  vector += vector2;
  vector2 -= vector;
}
```

I was wondering if there were any .NET IL optimizer tools? I've looked but having found anything really yet.  Or to be MORE clear, anyway to optimize my C# code or IL code for performance.

I really would like to see the operators perform at LEAST 185ms. It only makes sense for it too.

**Here is a link to the app im using for testing:** [Download](http://www.reign-studios.com/Share/PerformanceTest45.zip)

Comment: Are you running under the debugger?

Comment: @ReedCopsey No I'm building in Release .NET 4.5 x86.  Running on a AMD 64 x2 processor.

Comment: How are you running and timing this?  Are you running from within VS?

Comment: @vcsjones IL code optimization is not pointless.  It would cause poor boot times if that was so.  Also its the IL code at fault here not the JIT I would think?

Comment: @ReedCopsey No I compile the application via VS-2012, then execute the console app through explorer.  I am using the Stopwatch to measure time and even set "TimeBeginPeriod(1)" to ONE to make sure the Stopwatch is very accurate.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Here is a link to the app i'm using: http://www.reign-studios.com/Share/PerformanceTest45.zip

Comment: what are the times if the order is reversed?

Comment: @RuneFS I assume you mean subtract before addition in each test case??  If so they are exactly the same.  Just tested.

Comment: I mean if you do += and -= after vector.Add and vector2.Sub

Comment: @RuneFS No each test case is done alone and measured by itself.  I will update the question to make this more clear.

Comment: I edited out your Microsoft judgement as it is nonfactual and I am allergic to it. Please keep it neutral on stack overflow.

Comment: Test1 and Test2 are creating extra objects. I think that's the reason why they are slower, not because the IL is not optimised...

Comment: @PaoloTedesco You were right! I modified my operators so they dont create new objects and now they actually perform by far the fastest :)

Comment: @zezba9000 To repeat Reed's question: Do you run in a debugger? You can run a release build in the debugger, which by default will disable JIT optimization.

Comment: @usr Yes I said to much to soon. :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos No I do NOT run with the debugger.  I run the .exe by browsing to the compiled .exe and launching it through explorer like any normal app.

Comment: Btw on .net 4.5 you could use [`MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx) to encourage inlining.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes I actually tried that, but .NET already inlines it, so it didn't change anything. Tnx though.

Comment: You may want to check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578116/Complete-Managed-Media-Aggregation-Part-III-Quantu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own answer and the comments all give a strong hint to why calling .Add is faster than using the addition operator.

The semantics of `+` is that the operands are left untuched. Doing 1 +2 you wouldn't expect that 1 had the value of 3 afterwards would you? SO to follow the rule of least surprise the addition operators in various implementations follow this semantic.

This also means that the addition operator for vector4 needs to create a new Vector4 object. The memory for this new object might already be allocated (e.g. the stack) but that does not help much because we will have to copy that value when it is assigned to whatever the return type is assigned to.

The semantics of the Add instance method is different from the addition operator. It mutates one of the instances and therefor does not have to create a new object.

Your semantics of the addition operator in your posted answer are equivalent to that of the `add`

Comment: Why would creating a new `Vector4` be time consuming? It's a value type. And why are you talking about V-table look ups?

Comment: @CodesInChaos because memory allocation isn't free

Comment: There is no real memory allocation when you do `new SomeValueType`. There is no real reason why the OP's `+=` code should result in different machine code from a `new Vector3(...)` based code.

Comment: @RuneFS I understand what going on by what you said, and is why an IL optimizer would also help to clean up little issues like this all over the place.

Comment: @CodeInChaos how would you eliminate the resulting copy from the stack to the heap? (or another stackframe) I can't see how this is eliminated from the machine code without changing the semantics of the program

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution to my problem... Although I would still like any information on .NET IL optimizers.  Also It would be interesting to know why using operators are actually faster then manually inclining the code yourself?

To get the best performance with Vector4 operators on .NET do the following:

```
public static Vector4 operator +(Vector4 p1, Vector4 p2)
{
    p1.X += p2.X;
    p1.Y += p2.Y;
    p1.Z += p2.Z;
    p1.W += p2.W;
    return p1;
}

public static Vector4 operator -(Vector4 p1, Vector4 p2)
{
    p1.X -= p2.X;
    p1.Y -= p2.Y;
    p1.Z -= p2.Z;
    p1.W -= p2.W;
    return p1;
}
```

**DONT DO:**

```
public static Vector4 operator +(Vector4 p1, Vector4 p2)
{
    return new Vector4(p1.X+p2.X, p1.Y+p2.Y, p1.Z+p2.Z, p1.W+p2.W);
}
//ect...
```

Comment: Why such ugly code? a simple `return new Vector4(p1.X+p2.X,...)` would probably just as fast, but is much nicer. You don't really create instances of a value type.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Actually thats what I was doing that was so slow.  230ms vs 75ms.  Which one would you pick?

Comment: weird. Seems like the optimizer is behaving in a stupid way. There is no reason why this should be faster. I'll need to investigate this.

Comment: @CodeInChaos so value types do not need memory allocated? that's a surprise to me. Where are they stored then?

Comment: @RuneFS Local variable of a value type will be stored on the stack (or in some cases in registers), most of the time.

Comment: @svick which doesn't really improve things now does it? First we push the value onto the stack and then we copy it to whatever the return value is assigned to